# How to send gmail email with asp.net - c#?

Tags: asp.net

hi i want to send a some form entries resulting in a  postback to be mailed automatically with my gmail account to the target mail id entered by the user with asp.net - c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gmail lets you send mail var SMTP you should just be able to use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class in the .net framework.

**Do you however often have to configure your virus scanner to allow out going emails from the process the Asp.net is running in.**

Answer (score 3):

You can send an email using: http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Gmail uses the mail server that you can configure (I forget the exact address, but you can find it on the google site) your web application to use when it sends mail.